# When you meet someone somewhere by chance

Tags: word-usage, sentence-construction, word-request, sentence-structure

Which choice sounds natural in the following made-up scenario?

> a) Have you heard from Tom? There is no word from him recently! 
>   b) I was at a party last night. ................................ But unfortunately we didn't come up to each other at all.

1) He was there by chance too. 
2) Accidentally he was there too.

I wonder if there is a better choice in natural and idiomatic English. I have an intuition that my construction of the sentence is not valid and there is a much better way to convey the same concept.

Comment: I would use the word coincidentally: Coincidentally, he was there too, but, unfortunately, we didn't see each other. (I think you may want to consider amending your but... statement as it doesn't quite read right).

Comment: No problem! Glad I could help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

He also **happened** to be there, but unfortunately, we didn't **bump into** each other.

Comment: Thank you @Kaique. I've heard this usage. I think your suggested structure means the same as Bee's (Coincidentally) just your is more causal and informal. Do you agree?

Comment: Yes. Coincidentally is kind of a big word for me, so, I would say yes. It is more formal to say **coincidentally**.

Answer (score 0):

I would use the word coincidentally:

> Coincidentally, he was there too, but, unfortunately, we didn't see each other.

(I think you may want to consider amending your but... statement as it doesn't quite read right).

Comment: Thank you very much @Bee. But what's wrong with "we didn't come up to each other"?

Comment: It just doesn't sound right here, but I can't put my finger on the reason why. I think it would be technically correct.

Comment: @A-friend may I ask why you removed my answer as the answer to your question?

Comment: Well @Bee what Kaique says is closer to the concept that I was looking for while the adjective "coincidentally" works, but in much more formal cases. This is what I learned from Kaique. If my takeaway is incorrect, then please kindly let me know. I need to know more Bee. :)

Comment: I think "to come up to each other" is more like a British expression if I'm not wrong. I don't usually hear that in the US.

Comment: When somebody comes up to you they're usually asking a question or trying to talk to you about something important. For example: "He **came up to me** about how much he was going to make in the company"

Comment: In a case like that it would be better to say "We didn't see each other", "we didn't talk to each other", "We didn't bump into each other".

Comment: Come up to each other doesn't sound right, but he came up to me does work in the UK.